# NativeUIManager.getConstantsForViewManager('Text') threw an exception.Calling synchronous methods on native modules is not supported in Chrome

Tags: react-native

I'm getting two similar warning (one for image and other for text) in the default latest ReactNative demo on running the application in debug mode (No additional custom dependencies added). There are different posts around this error but all are because of adding a dependency. I haven't added any dependency.

```
},
 "dependencies": {
   "react": "17.0.2",
   "react-native": "0.65.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@babel/core": "7.15.5",
   "@babel/runtime": "7.15.4",
   "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "2.0.0",
   "babel-jest": "26.6.3",
   "eslint": "7.14.0",
   "jest": "26.6.3",
   "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.0",
   "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
   "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
 },
```

[image: Warning Screenshot]

I don't want to edit the MessageQueue.js to suppress this as is mentioned in a new post. Should I downgrade RN to some other version or is there any other fix without side effects?
**OS = BigsurOS.   Emulator = Pixel5 (Android R)**

----UPDATE----
Downgrading ReactNative to 0.64 doesn't cause this issue. Hence, it's a problem with 0.65 only